# Complex custom post type multiple loops in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops

I have a custom post type for **Staff Members** of an organisation with a taxonomy named Profession. I'm using easytabs to display a matrix of photos for each member sorted into different professions. When a user clicks on the photo (the tab navigation), the appropriate information is displayed in the panel as it animates to view.

I can only fit 4 members in each tab container div across the page, any more and the 5th one breaks the tab layout.

I need a loop to pull only 4 Staff Members per container, then the next 4 etc.

This is the code I have so far ...

```
<div class="team_content">
            <?php
                $custom_terms = get_terms('profession');

                foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
                    wp_reset_query();
                        $args = array('post_type' => 'team_members',
                            'tax_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'profession',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
                                ),
                            ),
                         );

                         $loop = new WP_Query($args);
                         if($loop->have_posts()) {
                            echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>'; //displays the profession

                            echo '<div class="tab-collapsible-container">';
                                echo '<ul>';

                            while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); //first sub-loop

                                //extract field names from metaboxes
                                $salutation = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_salutation', true );
                                $title = $salutation.' '.get_the_title();
                                $full_title = get_the_title();
                                $title_link = str_replace(' ','',$full_title); 
                                $final_title_link = strtolower($title_link);

                                echo '<li><a href="#'.$final_title_link.'">';
                                the_post_thumbnail("team-member");
                                echo '<h4>'.$title.'</h4></a></li>';

                            endwhile;

                                echo '</ul>';

                            rewind_posts();

                            echo '<div class="panel-container">';

                            while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

                                //extract field names from metaboxes
                                $profession = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_profession', true );
                                $qualifications = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_qualifications', true );
                                $services_url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_services_url', true );
                                $full_title2 = get_the_title();
                                $title_link2 = str_replace(' ','',$full_title2); 
                                $final_title_link2 = strtolower($title_link2);

                                echo '<div id="'.$final_title_link2.'" class="member_info">';
                                    echo '<h4>'.$profession.' '.$qualifications.'</h4>';
                                    the_content();
                                    echo '<a href="'.$services_url.'" class="button2">Visit Service Page</a>'; //Services page link
                                echo '</div>';

                            endwhile;

                            echo '</div>'; //panel-container

                            }

                        echo '</div>'; //tab-collapsible-container

                        }
                    ?>



        </div><!-- .team_content -->
```

Thank you @anstrangel0ver for the quick reply! I have tried with the counter & % operator all over the loop with no success. I'm thinking it would be more along the lines of the following code from [perishable press](http://perishablepress.com/multiple-loops-and-multiple-columns-with-wordpress/) as follows ...

```
// FIRST LOOP: display posts 1 thru 5
<?php query_posts('showposts=5'); ?>
<?php $posts = get_posts('numberposts=5&offset=0'); foreach ($posts as $post) :     start_wp(); ?>
<?php static $count1 = 0; if ($count1 == "5") { break; } else { ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php $count1++; } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>


// SECOND LOOP: display posts 6 thru 10
<?php query_posts('showposts=5'); ?>
<?php $posts = get_posts('numberposts=5&offset=5'); foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
<?php static $count2 = 0; if ($count2 == "5") { break; } else { ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php $count2++; } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

// THIRD LOOP: etc
    ..................

Just not sure how to apply this to my loop and keep everything right.

Comment: under the main loop use a variable $i=1 and increase it with counter $i++, and use if condition $i%4==0 and if true place the containter div again so now u get a container div after every 4 posts. may be i havent got what you said ..anyway..

Comment: Thank you friend for the quick reply! I have tried with the counter & % operator all over the loop with no success. I'm thinking it would be more along the lines of the following code from [link](http://perishablepress.com/multiple-loops-and-multiple-columns-with-wordpress/) as follows ...

Answer (score 0):

Yikes, this is messy business with that `rewind_posts()` in there. First I'd make a function that can advance your custom WP_Query by a certain number of posts:

```
function offset_posts($loop, $offset) {
    $post_counter = 0;
    while ($loop->have_posts() && ($post_counter < $offset) {
        $loop->next_post();
        $post_counter++;
    }
}
```

Then I would pull your staff member output code into a function that can write one block of four staff members at a time:

```
function output_staff_members($loop, $offset, $number_to_output = 4) {
    // skip posts until we get to $offset
    offset_posts($loop, $offset);

    $post_counter = 0;
    while ($loop->have_posts() && ($post_counter < $number_to_output)) :  //first sub-loop
        $loop->the_post();
        $post_counter++;

        //extract field names from metaboxes
        $salutation = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_salutation', true );
        $title = $salutation.' '.get_the_title();
        $full_title = get_the_title();
        $title_link = str_replace(' ','',$full_title); 
        $final_title_link = strtolower($title_link);

        echo '<li><a href="#'.$final_title_link.'">';
        the_post_thumbnail("team-member");
        echo '<h4>'.$title.'</h4></a></li>';

    endwhile;

    echo '</ul>';

    $loop->rewind_posts();
    offset_posts($loop, $offset);

    echo '<div class="panel-container">';

    $post_counter = 0;
    while ($loop->have_posts() && ($post_counter < $number_to_output)) :  //second sub-loop
        $loop->the_post();
        $post_counter++;

        //extract field names from metaboxes
        $profession = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_profession', true );
        $qualifications = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_qualifications', true );
        $services_url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_services_url', true );
        $full_title2 = get_the_title();
        $title_link2 = str_replace(' ','',$full_title2); 
        $final_title_link2 = strtolower($title_link2);

        echo '<div id="'.$final_title_link2.'" class="member_info">';
            echo '<h4>'.$profession.' '.$qualifications.'</h4>';
            the_content();
            echo '<a href="'.$services_url.'" class="button2">Visit Service Page</a>'; //Services page link
        echo '</div>';

    endwhile;

    echo '</div>'; //panel-container

    return $post_counter;
}
```

Lastly you'll just need to call that new function enough times to output all the staff members:

```
<div class="team_content">
        <?php
            $custom_terms = get_terms('profession');

            foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
                wp_reset_query();
                    $args = array('post_type' => 'team_members',
                        'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'profession',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
                            ),
                        ),
                     );

                     $loop = new WP_Query($args);
                     if($loop->have_posts()) {
                        echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>'; //displays the profession

                        echo '<div class="tab-collapsible-container">';
                        echo '<ul>';

                        // NEW CODE HERE:
                        $post_counter = 0;
                        while ($post_counter < $loop->$post_count) {
                            $post_counter += output_staff_members($loop, $post_counter);
                        }

                     }

                     echo '</div>'; //tab-collapsible-container

                 }
            ?>



    </div><!-- .team_content -->
```

Hope that works for you!

Comment: Wow thanks Nate! Now I'm not sure where to place all this extra code. The first 2 are functions so I've tried adding them to functions.php and replacing my old code with the 3rd block of code you supplied but it's not working.